# mixpanel not working in 2011 samsung smart tv but working fine in 2013

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, mixpanel

mixpanel is not working in 2011 smart TV I put Script tag in head that same code 
working fine in 2013 TV
Is there any problem in 2011 to add Script tag in body??

Answer (score 1):

Opps! finally found solution script tag copied from mixpanel has one url in it format is like ("//cdn.something.com") so that we need to replace with("http://cdn.something.com") adding http: will work coz in 2011 mappel engine TV not append it automatically but in 2012 onwards TV append it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Samsung 2013 devices uses WebKit browser engine, Samsung 2011 uses Maple browser engine.

Check that Mixpanel does not use [features](http://samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Spec) unsupported in Maple browser.